# How to display application/pdf response from Rails API to Nuxt frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axios, nuxt.js, prawn

I'm using Nuxt and Rails to generate PDF.

Chose `prawn` gem for PDF, and when send proper params, PDF was generates as I intended.

When I use this API from Nuxt throw axios, I want to display application/pdf response to Nuxt frontend

params

```
{
 name: "myName",
 address1: "Tokyo",
 address2: "Minato-ku"
}
```

request

```
const config = {
      responseType: 'blob',
}
const res = await this.$axios.post('/v1/orders', params, config)
=> res.data is like "Blob{size: 12345, type:"application/pdf"}"
```

I want to display this data as PDF on Nuxt frontend, thanks.

Comment: All right, a lot of things here. Let's try to narrow it down. You do have a route to generate the PDF from Rails? Does it work if you call it while staying on the same page, from a click on a button? Let's try to make this one work. Maybe without Vuex at first too.

Comment: Thanks, I narrow the problem down. The main problem is that I do not know how to display application/pdf response from API to Nuxt. So I modified the question.

Comment: I didn't found a fake API to try this thing out but you should be okay using something like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#extracting_data_from_a_blob Set the blob content into a `result` variable and you should be able to see it with this `<embed :src="result" width="500" height="500"></embed>` I think.